# IE8 ignoring vertical padding and margin

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I can't figure out why on the following page, from the Pricing section onwards, IE8 seems to ignore a lot of vertical padding and margin:

http://tinyurl.com/qd9s94y

Namely, it is ignoring margin-bottom on the Pricing heading, it is not applying vertical padding to the divs that make up the pricing table, and the links in the footer have also lost their vertical padding.

t works in every other browser, for comparison.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try editing your answer to include your code.

Comment: Hi @PlantTheIdea. I'm guessing it is something elsewhere in the page causing a problem as a simple h2 element is losing it's 'margin-bottom'. There are 1000 lines of code for this site, and  I don't think it would help to post the whole code here when everyone can inspect with Dev Tools.

Comment: correct ... it was implied, but perhaps I should have been more explicit. when asking a question on Stackoverflow, provide the code related to the specific problem you are looking at (not everything). in this case, the HTML and CSS for that menu. pictures do not help at all when trying to solve the problem, hence the complete lack of response from anyone else for your quesiton.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that IE8 doesn't support rem units for font-size.

My IE8 dev tools sprang to life so I could see what wasn't working.